# CodeMirror and Brackets, Custom Mode with CSS Quick Edit

Tags: javascript, codemirror, adobe-brackets, codemirror-modes

I'm making a Adobe Brackets Extension to add support for Laravel Blade syntax highlight.

Blade is a template system that runs on top of HTML (more specifically a .php file), without my extension active I can do CTRL+E **Quick Edit** on a css rule name to quickly find that rule on the stlye.css file.
But when I activate the extension, the CTRL+E is not working anymore, but the HTML syntax is working perfectly.

I'm using overlay mode over text/html.

Here is the main.js extension code:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';

    var LanguageManager = brackets.getModule("language/LanguageManager");


    CodeMirror.defineMode("laravelblade", function (config, parserConfig) {
        var mustacheOverlay = {
            token: function (stream, state) {

                var ch;

                //Highlight Comments {{-- --}}
                if (stream.match("{{--")) {
                    while ((ch = stream.next()) != null)
                        if (ch == "}" && stream.next() == "}") break;
                    stream.eat("}");
                    return "comment";
                }
                //--

                //Highlight {{ $var }})
                if (stream.match("{{")) {
                    while ((ch = stream.next()) != null)
                        if (ch == "}" && stream.next() == "}") break;
                    stream.eat("}");
                    return "def";
                }

                //Highlight {% $var %} (Laravel 5)
                else if (stream.match('{%')) {
                    while ((ch = stream.next()) != null)
                        if (ch == "%" && stream.next() == "}") break;
                    stream.eat("}");
                    return "def";
                }

                //Highlight {% $var %} (Laravel 5)
                else if (stream.match('{%')) {
                    while ((ch = stream.next()) != null)
                        if (ch == "%" && stream.next() == "}") break;
                    stream.eat("}");
                    return "def";
                }

                //Return Null if no condition was met.
                else if (stream.next() != null) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.backdrop || "php"), mustacheOverlay);
    });


    LanguageManager.defineLanguage("laravelblade", {
        "name": "Laravel Blade",
        "mode": "laravelblade",
        "fileExtensions": ["blade.php"],
        "blockComment": ["{{--", "--}}"]
    });
});
```

The real question is:
**How can I add support for Quick Edit on my custom mode and *blade.php files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this part of your code:

```
            else if (stream.next() != null) {
                return null;
            }
```

Looking at [CodeMirror's overlay mode demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html), it does something slightly different:

```
  while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match("{{", false)) {}
  return null;
```

Your code is returning null once for each ignored character, while the demo is only returning null once per *contiguous chunk* of ignored characters.

Returning separately for every character seems to make CodeMirror break up all of its normal tokens into separate one-char tokens, which the Brackets Quick Edit code can't recognize -- e.g. if your cursor is here - `cl|ass` - CodeMirror says it's in an attribute token where the name is just "l", while the Brackets code is looking attributes named "class".

Comment: Btw, you should also add `var CodeMirror = brackets.getModule("thirdparty/CodeMirror2/lib/codemirror");` near the top - accessing CodeMirror as a global is deprecated and will go away soon. (It should be printing console warnings about this).

Comment: I knewn that (read it exactly on the console), but din't changed it yet (lazy me... changed now :) ). Thank you!

Comment: @ytepe Thank you for your help.
I see what you are doing on your code, however will I need to declare every new rule on the "while" loop?

Comment: It does look like it, but match() supports regexes so it might still be pretty compact: `while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match(/{[{%]/, false))`.

Comment: Oh! Great!
May I ask you how to do multi-line? Or shall I make a new question?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means without more detail, so I'd say post it as a new question so there's room to add more info :-)